# Extra zero when calculating a linear trendline

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I am attempting to write an algorithm in $c++$ to calculate a linear trendline. The issue is when I am doing examples by hand, I get a slope that is $10^4$ whereas I believe it should be $10^3$. The results I get are also not the same as excel or any online calculators give me.

So I followed the equations given [in the selected answer of this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204020/what-is-the-equation-used-to-calculate-a-linear-trendline). So this my working:

```
+-----+----------+----------+-------+  
|  x  |    y     |   x*y    |  x^2  |  
+-----+----------+----------+-------+  
| 155 | 0.116142 | 18.00201 | 13225 |  
| 127 | 0.077622 | 9.857994 | 16129 |  
| 113 | 0.058267 | 6.584171 | 12769 |  
+-----+----------+----------+-------+
```

$$\begin{align}
\sum x &= 395\\  
\sum y &= 0.252031\\     
\sum xy &= 34.444175\\   
\sum x^2 &= 42123\\
\end{align}$$
Now this is exactly what I am calculating using the slope equation linked above:

$$\frac {\left(3 \times \sum xy\right) - \left(\sum x \times \sum y\right)}{\left(3 \times \sum x^2\right) - \left(\sum x\right)^2}$$
which is $$\frac{103.332525 - 99.552245}{126369 - 156025}\\  
= -1.274710008 \times 10^{-4}\\  
= -0.000127471$$

Now for the offset equation shown in the link I do:

$$\sum y - \text{slope}\left(\sum x\right) / 3$$
which is $$(0.252031 - -0.000127471(395)) / 3\\
=0.100794015$$

This gives me the result of $$y = -0.000127471x + 0.100794015$$

In excel and the online calculators I get $$y = 0.0013776399x - 0.0973791029$$
My values look close, but are still not correct, with the first having an extra zero (being $10^{-4}$ not $10^{-3}$) and the signs being reversed.

I must be missing something somewhere but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, can anybody see my error?

Comment: You have incorrectly calculated $155^2=24025\neq13225=115^2$. Simple typo on your calculator.

Comment: I can't believe I did that. Thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: No problem. Its always those sort of errors that are hardest for oneself to find.