# Linear regression without intercept: formula for slope

Tags: linear-algebra, regression

To do linear regression there is good answer from [TecHunter](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204020/what-is-the-equation-used-to-calculate-a-linear-trendline)

Slope;

$$\alpha = {n\sum(xy) - \sum x \sum y \over n\sum x^2 - (\sum x)^2}$$

Offset:

$$\beta = {\sum y - \alpha \sum x \over n}$$

Trendline formula:

$$y = \alpha x + \beta $$

However, How does these formulas change when I want to force interception at origin ? I want $y=0$ when $x=0$,
so model is:
$$y = \alpha x $$

Comment: Do you mean find the $\alpha$ such that $\sum (y_i - \alpha x_i)^2$ is minimized where $(x_i,y_i)$ are the data points? So even if the data are like $(i,1)$ which should give the horizontal line $y=1$, you will give a terrible answer because it has to pass through the origin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To fit the zero-intercept linear regression model $y=\alpha x + \epsilon$ to your data $(x_1,y_1),\ldots,(x_n,y_n)$, the least squares estimator of  $\alpha$ minimizes the error function
$$
L(\alpha):=\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\alpha x_i)^2.\tag1
$$
Use calculus to minimize $L$, treating everything except $\alpha$ as constant. Differentiating (1) wrt $\alpha$ gives
$$
L'(\alpha) = \sum2(y_i-\alpha x_i)(-x_i)=-2\left(\sum x_iy_i - \alpha\sum x_i^2\right).\tag2
$$
Setting (2) to zero yields the equation
$$
\sum x_iy_i=\alpha\sum x_i^2\tag3
$$
which you can solve for $\alpha$ to obtain the estimator for the slope:
$$\hat\alpha = \frac{\sum x_iy_i}{\sum x_i^2}.
$$
Remember to check that the second derivative of $L$ is positive, to confirm that $L$ is minimized for this $\hat\alpha$. Indeed, $L''(\alpha)=2\sum x_i^2$, which doesn't depend on $\alpha$, and is positive except in the degenerate case where all the $x$'s are exactly zero. In that case you will agree that there's no unique line passing through the origin that best fits the data.

Comment: I tested against Excel and I got same results, thanks

Answer (score -2):

Since $\beta=0$, $\alpha = \frac{\sum y}{\sum x}$

Comment: Could you please detail how you got there?

Comment: Since $\beta=0$,  $\beta = {\sum y - \alpha \sum x \over n} = 0 \implies \alpha = \frac{\sum y}{\sum x}$

Comment: I am getting wrong results

Comment: Why do you want to force the line through origin in the first place?  May be the true line which generated the data has some intercept (the line with the least MSE). @grand_chat's answer makes more sense.

Comment: This is completely wrong.