# How do I calculate the regression equation of $y = ax^2$ (find the coefficient $a$ that gives the smallest sum of squares of errors)?

Tags: linear-algebra, regression-analysis

The input is a group of points $(x,y)$. I am trying to find the regression equation of $y = ax^2$ (I am trying to find the coefficient $a$ that gives the smallest sum of squares of errors from the input points. How do I find this?

[What I have tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umIFP.png)

I tried to calculate coefficient a like above, but the result was not what I expected.

Thank you.

Comment: What you did is correct.

Comment: The formula looks OK. I've tried to write a short script in python, and it yields the correct result

Comment: Hi Han. The solution looks correct.

Comment: Thank you all for confirming that my solution was correct. I just realized that I was doing the math wrong. I was doing (Σy*Σx^2)/(Σx^4), instead of (Σ(y*x^2))/(Σx^4). A stupid mistake haha. I got the correct result now! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regression equation is modeling the response $y$ as a linear function of $x^2$, with no intercept. So formally it is the same problem as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3297060/215011), except you replace every occurrence of $x_i$ with $x_i^2$. The result will agree with your calculation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!